# Google sheet help need formula fill auto

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

hello i am trying to get 5% of upcoming result auto in case of new value entered in Cell **C** i have try below formula but its not work .i want formula auto fill in case of new value in C

arrayformula(IF(C5:C=""."".(D4*1.05)))
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any array in the `value_if_false`.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(C5:C="",,D4*POWER(1.05,ROW(C5:C)-ROW(D4))))
```

Comment: Its not working

Comment: Sorry its working